# emacs how to bind "LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK" to a keystroke

Tags: emacs

I want to type a single keystroke to insert unicode brackets #xab and #xbb.

This works (for a different unicode bracket):
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c [") "⟨")

But this doesn't work:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c [") "«")

How do I coax emacs into inserting "«" with a single keystroke?

(I happen to be on MacOS, but intend to use ubuntu in Parallels)

Comment: You might be interested in the [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), which is the usual way of binding emacs-like shortcuts into unicode glyphs that are usually not on your keyboard. The main advantage is that this works at a much lower level, and therefore everywhere you type (as opposed to only within Emacs). IDK on MacOS, but on Ubuntu you probably just need to enable it in the settings, and then with the default configuration typing `Compose < <` will produce `«`.

Comment: @BlackBeans: You might want to convert your comment into an answer: it's a better answer than the accepted one IMO, precisely because it is more general, not just applicable to Emacs.

Comment: @NickD indeed, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`m not sure what is expected, `double ⟨ or one «`, but hope this can help

check [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html) and [loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html)

```
(defun my-insert () 
  "test something"
  (interactive)
  (dotimes (i 2)
  (insert "⟨"))
)

(defun my-insert2 () 
  "test something"
  (interactive)
  (insert "«")
)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c [") 'my-insert)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c ]") 'my-insert2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a more general solution which works everywhere, making it more convenient (as you may not want to open an emacs instance each time you need a particular character), which is the compose key. Compose key is specific to Linux, but there is [a way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31487/add-compose-key-to-os-x) to install an equivalent solution on MacOS, and you can even [convert](http://bob.cakebox.net/osxcompose.php) existing Compose Key bindings, which is useful because there are a lot of predefined sequences out there in the wild, for instance [the default ones](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre?id=c0670e5d3ae330e611ecb05303d579a4f8a3d114).

E.g.  on Ubuntu you probably just need to enable it in the settings, and then with the default configuration typing `Compose < <` will produce `«`.

Comment: Added the example from your comment: it is always important to answer the specific question.